How to apply changes on a removing item in SwiftUI?
Setup:
I have a simple view that animates its color when needed:
struct SelfAnimatingView: View {
    let name: String
    let animate: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            .padding()
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .background(animate ? .red : .blue)
    }
}

And a simple list of removable items :
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var removable = false
    @State private var names = ["Ted", "Barney", "Lily", "Robin", "Marshal"]
    @State private var animatedNames =  Set<String>()
    private var unanimatedNames: [String] { names.filter({ !animatedNames.contains($0) }) }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Removable", isOn: $removable).padding()
            ForEach(removable ? unanimatedNames : names, id: \.self) { name in
                Button { animatedNames.insert(name) } label: {
                    SelfAnimatingView(name: name, animate: animatedNames.contains(name))
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .animation(.default.delay(1), value: unanimatedNames)
    }
}


Behaviour
The SelfAnimatingView animates when the Removable switch is off as expected:

But as soon as the delete logic involved, the self-contained animation stops working:

It seems SwiftUI does not apply any changes on the (logically) already removed item.

Question
So how can we make it apply the self-contained changes before it is deleted visually?

You would have to do this in a two-step process, I think, because you don't have separate control over the animation that ForEach does, over the transition animation.

While the problem of "SwiftUI doesn't update views that are already removed" can be solved by writing your own custom Transition, the color change will occur at the same time as the other views moving up to fill its place.
You cannot control the animations of the ForEach moving the other buttons up, separately from the pressed button changing its color. This must be done in two separate animations.
You can create a custom View that wraps the Button. This will use a separate @State to animate the color change first, and only then remove itself from the view hierarchy by calling animatedNames.insert(name).
struct CustomButton: View {
    let name: String
    @Binding var names: Set<String>
    @State private var flag = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // this guard is not needed in this case, because
            // calling names.insert(name) twice will have the same effect as
            // calling it only once.
            // In general, you need this guard to prevent side effects from
            guard !flag else { return }
            withAnimation {
                flag = true
            } completion: {
                names.insert(name)
            }
        } label: {
            SelfAnimatingView(name: name, animate: flag)
        }
    }
}

Usage:
// also consider wrapping this whole if statement in the custom view
if removable {
    CustomButton(name: name, names: $animatedNames)
} else {
    Button { animatedNames.insert(name) } label: {
        SelfAnimatingView(name: name, animate: animatedNames.contains(name))
    }
}


Cool +1, this also preserves the source of truth to be single. It is a shame that the completion is only available from iOS 17 in this API.

You can get it to work if the array unanimatedNames is a state variable that is rebuilt every time an item is selected, instead of having it as a computed property.

Rebuild it in an .onChange handler that is triggered by changes to animatedNames.
In iOS17, you can use the initial flag to build it on first show, in previous iOS versions, .onAppear could be used instead.

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var removable = false
    @State private var names = ["Ted", "Barney", "Lily", "Robin", "Marshal"]
    @State private var animatedNames = Set<String>()
    @State private var unanimatedNames = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // content as before
        }
        .animation(.default.delay(1), value: unanimatedNames)
        .onChange(of: animatedNames, initial: true) {
            unanimatedNames = names.filter { !animatedNames.contains($0) }
        }
    }
}



Interesting approach +1, I'm thinking of the downsides like having multiple sources of truth and waste of memory for larger datasets.

inspired by the @Sweeper's answer, we can define a generic animatable button like:
struct DelayedButton<Label: View>: View {
    var animation: Animation = .default
    let label: (_ triggered: Bool) -> Label
    var completion: () -> Void
    @State private var isTriggered = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            withAnimation(animation, { isTriggered = true }, completion: completion)
        } label: { label(isTriggered) }
    }
}

Then we just need to use this inside the ForEach like:
DelayedButton { triggered in
    SelfAnimatingView(name: name, animate: triggered)
} completion: {
    animatedNames.insert(name)
}

Result

